# OpenGL rendering multiple textures on sprites

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 2d

I'm learning OpenGL from the MakingGamesWithBen series and I'm writing a simple asteroid shooter based on his engine. I have created a system that randomly positions the asteroid sprites with random sizing, and selects a random texture path from an std::vector, and passes the path to the asteroid constructor. The sprites are drawn, however only the first texture is drawn. I've read that I need to bind those textures and switch to the relevant glActiveTexture; from my code below, how would I go about this?

```
void MainGame::prepareTextures() {
//compile shaders and get Texlocations
initShaders("Shaders/background.vert", "Shaders/background.frag");
GLint TexLoc = _colorProgram.getUniformLocation("bgTexture");
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
}
```

m_asteroid[i].draw():

```
glm::vec4 uv(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

//convert m_imgNum to string and remove trailing zeros
std::string strImgNum = std::to_string(m_imgNum);
strImgNum.erase(strImgNum.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos);
//construct filpath
std::string filePath = m_dir + strImgNum + ".png";

static Engine::GLTexture texture = Engine::ResourceManager::GetTexture(filePath, 0, 0, 32, 4);

Engine::Color color;
color.r = 255;
color.g = 255;
color.b = 255;
color.a = 255;

glm::vec4 posAndSize = glm::vec4(m_posX, m_posY, m_width, m_height);

spriteBatch.Draw(posAndSize, uv, texture.id, 0.0f, color);
```

Engine::ResourceManager::GetTexture():

```
GLTexture texture = {};

    unsigned char *imageData = stbi_load(filePath.c_str(), &width, &height, &bitsPerPixel, forceBpp);

    if (imageData == NULL) {
        const char *loadError = stbi_failure_reason();
        stbi_image_free(imageData);
        fatalError(loadError);
    }

    //Create the texture in opengl
    glGenTextures(1, &(texture.id));

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.id);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);

    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    stbi_image_free(imageData);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    texture.width = width;
    texture.height = height;

    return texture;
```

renderbatch():

```
void SpriteBatch::renderbatch() {

    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_renderBatches.size(); i++) {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_renderBatches[i].texture);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, m_renderBatches[i].offset, m_renderBatches[i].numVertices);
    }

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

I can provide any other code/clarification that may be needed!

Comment: You switch textures in OpenGL using glBendTexture(). The second parameter should be the ID of the texture that you got back from glGenTextures. Your example doesn't show where that's called.

Comment: Maybe a [texture atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) would be a better approach.

Comment: @moof2k, The tutorial I am following has everything dumped in the LoadImage function called by `Engine::ResourceManager::GetTexture(filePath, 0, 0, 32, 4);` I added that code to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when not all textures are showing up, it's probably has something to do with uploading the texture by OpenGL. You could try to debug this by checking if your textures are all uploaded properly;

```
std::uint32_t textureId = Engine::ResourceManager::GetTexture(filePath, 0, 0, 32, 4).id;
std::cout << "texture id, should not be 0 :" << textureId << std::endl;
```

This could happen if you called this function not from a thread with OpenGL context.

EDIT:
Is there any reason to use a static object here?

```
static Engine::GLTexture texture = Engine::ResourceManager::GetTexture(filePath, 0, 0, 32, 4);
```

try changing that to just

```
Engine::GLTexture texture = Engine::ResourceManager::GetTexture(filePath, 0, 0, 32, 4);
```

UPDATE:
 I just replaced your spitebatch.cpp/.h with the ones from Ben's github and put a simple test in your MainGame.cpp;

```
m_spriteBatch.begin();

asteroids.draw(m_spriteBatch);
ship.draw(m_spriteBatch);

m_spriteBatch.end();
m_spriteBatch.renderBatch();

_colorProgram.unuse();
_window.SwapBuffers();
```

and I can render the two uploaded textures properly;
[image]

HTH.

Comment: I used your debug code, and none of the texture id's are 0 (yay!). I also went into the image loader function and cout'ed if the images were loaded or not. Everything is being loaded correctly, but OpenGL is not drawing with the correct texture...

Comment: Is there any reason to use static Engine::GLTexture texture? That means the texture object is global to the whole application and I don't think that's what you need, am I right?

Comment: My bad :P There is still no difference though, I'm going to take a good look at the draw function in the sprite batch class to see if there is a bug there.

Comment: If your code is hosted publicly like on github then I can try to take a look at your code. The code that you posted above should work properly as intended so the mistake might probably be somewhere else.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://bitbucket.org/htmlboss/opengl-2d-game-engine/src) . I'm pretty sure the issue will be inside the "Bengine" folder (main engine).  The shooter game ("AsteroidShooter") basically uses functions from it. Feel free to download the solution (if you do, just comment out lines 5-7 in MainGame.h to disable the memory leak checker).

Comment: I updated my answer above after testing your code. Hope that would help you to retrace the bug.